# Socket in a async loop seems to return nothing

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I wanted to know asyncio in python better so decided to write a simple http proxy-server using only basic utilities such as sockets and asyncio.
Here is my code

```
import asyncio
import socket

BUFFER = 4096


class ProxyServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.listener.bind(("192.168.1.6", 80))
        self.listener.listen()

    async def invoke(self, loop):
        try:
            while 1:
                conn, addr = self.listener.accept()
                await self.process_new_conn(conn, loop)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            loop.stop()
            print("Finishing...")

    async def process_new_conn(self, conn, loop):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sender:
            data = await loop.sock_recv(conn, BUFFER)

            await loop.sock_connect(sender, (host, port))
            sender.send(data)

            response = await loop.sock_recv(sender, BUFFER)
            conn.send(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        ps = ProxyServer()
        loop.run_until_complete(ps.invoke(loop))
    except OSError:
        print("80 port is being used.")
    finally:
        loop.close()
```

As far as I understand it,  `loop.run_until_complete` adds my coro to loop's queue and executes it somewhen. When I call `await self.process_new_conn(conn, loop)` loop adds this coro to its queue. My question is how to put in the queue a loop? I mean it looks like the code in `process_new_conn` is executed but the other socket receives nothing, but when I try to type something like this `loop.run_until_complete(self.process_new_conn(conn, loop))` it works(with runtime error but still). It looks like there should be another approach but I can't find it.

UPD: I hope, my tests were wrong. That's all. But here my changed code with a small explanation, in case somebody will need.

```
import asyncio
import socket

from select import select

BUFFER = 4096


class ProxyServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.listener.bind(("localhost", 80))
        self.listener.listen()

        self.loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def invoke(self):
        try:
            self.loop.run_until_complete(self.accept_connection())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            self.loop.stop()
            self.loop.close()
            print("Finishing...")

    async def accept_connection(self):
        while 1:
            read, _, _ = select([self.listener], [], [], 0.1)
            if read:
                conn, addr = self.listener.accept()
                await self.process_new_conn(conn)

    async def process_new_conn(self, conn):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sender:
            data = await self.loop.sock_recv(conn, BUFFER)
            await self.loop.sock_connect(sender, (host, port))
            sender.send(data)

            response = await self.loop.sock_recv(sender, BUFFER)
            await self.loop.sock_sendall(conn, response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        ps = ProxyServer()
        ps.invoke()
    except OSError:
        print("80 port is being used.")
```

As I understand it: using `await` we say to a loop that coro should be put in a queue and may be interrupted(this let a loop to switch current coro at the wordd `await`). This video helped me a lot https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m28fiN9y_r8&t=679s

Comment: Could you rewrite your question after you read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve]?